# where should inheritance classes be stored?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create classes that can be inherited by other classes to use along my project.
i.e. i want to create a separate class for each Mail method, each class will implement differently the Compose method, and more Mail classes will be created in the future.

My question is - Where should I create these classes/interfaces? in the App_Code ?

Comment: What kind of ASP.NET project is this: WebForms for MVC? (You imply the former, but better to be clear.)

Comment: the former - webforms. i guess app_code is the easy way but may lead to delay on run time. so i will go for class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a separate assembly and include that assembly as a reference in your Web Project.  That will enable you to write independent test cases against your classes / interfaces.

Comment: @Yaniv: Correct. This is the way to go as the amount of code increases, but it does add a step to deployment (build the class library before copying `.dll` to the destination's bin folder).

Answer (score 1):

Other than user controls you can store source files in App_Code. In your case you can store Interfaces/classes in App_Code. You can have multiple folders for group of class/interfaces inside the AppCode.

[AppCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> You can store source code in the App_Code folder, and it will be
>   automatically compiled at run time. The resulting assembly is
>   accessible to any other code in the Web application. The App_Code
>   folder therefore works much like the Bin folder, except that you can
>   store source code in it instead of compiled code. The App_Code folder
>   and its special status in an ASP.NET Web application makes it possible
>   to create custom classes and other source-code-only files and use them
>   in your Web application without having to compile them independently.

Edit: You may see this discuss: [How to organize ASP.NET app_code folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922719/how-to-organize-asp-net-app-code-folder)

Comment: compiled at run time == compiled on the first run of the application ever, or for the first run after iisreset ?

Comment: The first items to be compiled are referred to as the top-level items. After the first request, the top-level items are recompiled only if a dependency changes. Top-level items include App_Code, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx